# taking database backup using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i want to take backup of my database on click event of button. i got somewhere that i can take  back up of my database using  **using SMO Objects BackUp & Restore** for this purpose i have to include following namespace

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```

for adding namespace i have to add a reference of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` in my project.
but i can't find these reference in my project. what to do now .
[image]

Comment: here is link of that code 
http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/307518-How-to-Backup-and-Restore-of-SQL-Server-database-through-c-net-asp-code.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies" folder. This should have the DLLs

Comment: So, add that as reference to your project.